# Google says Your device isn't compatible with this version

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I upload my app on google play store earlier and when I check it. It says 'your device isn't compatible with this version' but I am testing the app on my phone before uploading it.

```
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity3"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity4"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity5"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity6"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
    </activity>
</application>
```

I read from others question and it seems the problem is on manifest.'
What should I do to fix this problem?

EDIT: Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.user.proj"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':libraries:opencv')
```

}

Comment: should i use targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On line `<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>`, you are saing that you app only work on android 6 or less, just remove this line

Answer (score 0):

Your maxSdkVersion declaration seems to be problematic, you should remove this line. If the problem persists, post your gradle file content.

EDIT: android:maxSdkVersion usage is not recommended in the documentation. See below.

> Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible. Your application should work properly on new versions, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development best practices. Second, note that in some cases, declaring the attribute can result in your application being removed from users' devices after a system update to a higher API Level. Most devices on which your application is likely to be installed will receive periodic system updates over the air, so you should consider their effect on your application before setting this attribute.

Comment: Your gradle file seems to be ok. Just try removing maxSdkVersion line. See the edit in my answer.